# Scss styles not being applied in Storybook stories

Tags: sass, vuejs3, vite, storybook

I am trying to migrate my project from Vue 2 to Vue 3 and one of the things I need to make sure works is Storybook. In my Vue 2 project I used Storybook v6.5 but it doesn't want to play nicely with my Vue 3 project so I switched to Storybook v7.

The thing is although in my Vue 3 app's styles are present on my localhost preview they are missing in Storybook. I've got sass installed in my project and I am using Vite.

I am not sure if maybe I should import my styles inside of .storybook/main.js in spite of the fact that Vite should recognize scss files by default without the need of adding sass-loader or things like that.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be happening?

I tried to edit .storybook/main.js this way:

```
/** @type { import('@storybook/vue3-vite').StorybookConfig } */
const config = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions'
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/vue3-vite',
    options: {}
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: 'tag'
  },
  async viteFinal(config) {
    return mergeConfig(config, {
      css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
          scss: {
            additionalData: `@import '../src/assets/style.scss';`,
          },
        },
      },
    });
  },
}
export default config
```

But it resulted in Storybook starting but not being able to show any of my stories.
Currently everything works when I remove the `async viteFinal(config)` block, but then again styles are missing from Storybook :/

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to fix it since yesterday and only after posting a question on SO I found solution (hate when that happens). Import was needed on the top of .storybook/preview.js file like so:

`import "../src/assets/style.scss"`.